Does causality mean consequence or cause?
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/causality defines causality as:
1
: a causal quality or agency
2
: the relation between a cause and its effect or between regularly correlated events or phenomena

Does the first sense mean a cause not a consequence?
Does the meaning of causality in the following example from the link mean consequence not cause? Which sense in the definition applies to its use here?

The Unified Command salvage teams have located the body of another
victim of the Francis Scott Key Bridge disaster, bringing the total
number of causalities to six. —Stepheny Price, Fox News, 7 May 2024


I’m voting to close this question because a typographical error in the text cited in the question is the origin of the OP's confusion.

It’s a typographical error.  It should be casualties.

Asking whether causality means consequence or cause is like asking whether haircut means barber or client. Causality is the relationship between consequence and cause.
But anyway, as has already been answered, the source meant casualty.
